# How to solve: RenderEventToBuffer failed because of insufficient memory - Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

*Windows 2008 R2 server, 16G ram. MS SQL 2012, Max server mem set to 12G (not sure if the SQL info is relevant).*

I have an exe that has a function which can be run manually (click the button) or via a scheduled task (passing the correct param).

When the task gets run manually, all works fine.

When the task is run as a scheduled task, I get the following error:

```
RenderEventToBuffer failed because of insufficient memory -122-The data area passed to a system call is too small
```

[image: RenderEventToBuffer]

** The one thing that might be a hint OR could be a red herring, is that it seems after the sql server is restarted (and much less than it's 12G limit in memory) the scheduled task runs fine, but the error appears once the sql server hits the 12G memory limit.

As I write that, it really does seem red-herring-ish, but I don't know enough to know enough.

**Can anyone help me understand what this means and how to solve it?**

Comment: This issue is now not happening. Will continue to monitor.

Comment: Not sure what I should do about the question, whether I leave it or answer it?

Comment: I am getting the same problem now.Can you provide a solution for the above problem.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have an answer. What I thought was the solution was a red herring, something else was happening.

Comment: Google lead me here.  If you have anyone has insight it'll help future travelers.

Comment: This is the only Google link on the subject.  How did you solve it @StuAndrews?

Comment: Hi there. I suspect that it is a red herring. Couldn't find that it was actually doing anything bad, it was just appearing. Didn't stop my scheduled tasks from running fine.

Comment: I was seeing this on DebugView while I was monitoring a service.  I happened to be searching the event viewer which was the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what causes this but rebooting the server has fixed this for me across multiple systems when encountered.